# Can't connect to the internet using Huawei 3G USB modem

Tags: networking, unity, usb, 16.10

I previously used this dongle on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 without any problem but on 16.10 x64 I didn't see "New Mobile Broadband" menu under Network Manager icon when the dongle was inserted for awhile.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:15cd Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Open Terminal & Type Following :-

```
sudo apt install wvdial -y
sudo eject $( echo "$(ls /dev | grep sr) \n" | grep "\n" | awk '{print $1}' )
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x15cd
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x15cd
sudo wvdialconf 2>&1
sudo nmcli radio wwan on && sleep 3
sudo nmcli radio wwan on && sleep 2
sudo nmcli radio wwan on && sleep 1
```

Then mobile broadband will be available to create new connection.